# How to add inline css in WordPress plugin/theme generated by shortcode in page content?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a plugin and I need to correctly include inline css in WordPress using wp_add_inline_style() function. There is not problem to include CSS using this function in plugin, it works fine. But I have shortcodes that generates Custom CSS (different for different shortcode). For example I have shortcode that add text title with custom color to page (I generated unique CSS class name for this title DIV and add corresponding styles).

For example:
[mytitle text="Title example" color="#666666"]

And I have css that I need to inline:
.mytitle-id-4324324 h1 { color:#666666; }

As you see I can have multiple shortcodes on the same page, with different colors inside. The problem that if I use wp_add_inline_style function in shortcode it never not work. It should be inlined in "wp_enqueue_scripts" action, that does not triggered in right time from shortcode as I understand (because shortcodes loaded by WordPress AFTER wp_enqueue_scripts, when WordPress generate content). How to resolve this?

Note: I know that I can add inline CSS in HTML code or echo   and it works, but I does not need this. My question how to get this work with wp_enqueue_scripts()? 
As I understand I need to get one big global custom CSS from entire page shortcodes somehow, and then send it to some function that will include this big custom css for this page. But how to do this because shortcodes defenitions executed after including CSS by WordPress?

Example code for my shortcode:

```
function mgt_shortcode_header_block_wp($atts, $sc_content = null) {

.. some code here where shortcode show HTML output and generate custom css

}
add_shortcode("mgt_header_block_wp", "mgt_shortcode_header_block_wp");
```

How I can add inline custom css from shortcode? I can't do this inside shortcode (because its will not be called in **wp_enqueue_scripts** action) and I can't add some function after this function, because - custom css variable available only inside shortcode (I can't make it global var, because this is not good to use global vars here), I understand that I may need to pass it to some function from shortcode, something like:

```
function mgt_shortcode_header_block_wp($atts, $sc_content = null) {

.. some code here where shortcode show HTML output and generate custom css
  mgt_add_to_inline_styles($custom_css); // how should work this function to correctly add inline styles passed to it?


}
add_shortcode("mgt_header_block_wp", "mgt_shortcode_header_block_wp");
```

But this will not work, because **mgt_add_to_inline_styles()** function will be executed only when this shortcode will be used on page in content, and this will be AFTER wp_enqueue_scripts action in any case, even if I will try to add m**gt_add_to_inline_styles()** to **wp_enqueue_scripts** action somewhere somehow.

So from my example I does not understand what code should be inside **mgt_add_to_inline_styles()** function to make it work correctly?

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: I added sample code.